# how to modify mainform.ui components from other form, and vice versa

Tags: c++, qt

how can i modify mainform.ui components(Qlabels, comboBox, etc ) from other form, and vice versa.
ex: 1-mainform.ui has a button(so called "button1"), when i click button1 i want to disable a button located in otherform.ui (so called "button2")
2- when i click on otherform.ui's button2, i want to clear a comboBox , located in mainform.ui

In ex #1 : i dont know how to reference otherform.ui, using the way> otherform obj;
obj.ui.button2.disabled(); the compiler show me a error!.

in ex#2: in the otherform.cpp i referencie the mainform.ui, creating an object type mainform,(mainform obj;), and then obj.ui.comboBox.clear();, when i run the app, an error said > mainform *ui is private, so i go to the mainform.h and make it public, then no signals of errors happen, but nothing happens.

someone can help me? excuse my english.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SIGNAL and SLOT mechanism to send mouse clicks from one form to another. The only requirement needed is that the forms, you are referring to, will have to be treated as 'Q_Object'.

Example

Form 1

```
#include <QObject>                  //must include this

class Form1 : public QObject
{
 Q_OBJECT                            //must include this 

 public:
    Form1(){ connect(&btn1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(clicked_btn1())); }

 private:
    QPushButton btn1;

 public slots:                       /*slots are methods which are triggered when 
                                       signals are emitted */
    void disable_btn(){btn1.disable();}
    void clicked_btn1(){emit btn1_signal();}//signals are triggered by 'emit'

 signals:                           /*signals are events waiting to be triggered*/
    void btn1_signal();

};
```

Form 2

```
#include <QObject>                  //must include this

class Form2 : public QObject
{
 Q_OBJECT                            //must include this 

 public:
    Form2(){ connect(&btn2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(clicked_btn2())); }

 private:
    QPushButton btn2;
    QComboBox cmb;

 public slots:                       /*slots are methods which are triggered when 
                                       signals are emitted */
    void clear_cmb(){cmb.clear();}
    void clicked_btn2(){emit btn2_signal();}//signals are triggered by 'emit'

 signals:                           /*signals are events waiting to be triggered*/
    void btn2_signal();
```

;
    };

Main

```
//include all the header files of form1 and form2
//include <QObject> file and Q_OBJECT

Form1 *form_1 = new Form1();
Form2 *form_2 = new Form2();

//connecting signals from one form to slots of another form
connect(form_1, SIGNAL(btn1_signal()), form_2, SLOT(disable_btn()))
connect(form_2, SIGNAL(btn2_signal()), form_1, SLOT(clear_cmb()))
```

So this is how a button from one object can be disabled from a click of a button inside another object.

Since this is a big topic, here's a link from Qt with more explanation and simple examples
http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html